ACPI BIOS ERROR/ Busybox initramfs
I started my computer and immediatly get this problem. I try the command exit to get the exact problem, but I didn't find a solution for it.
I am a very new Ubuntu user, so I would like some help to solve this issue.


This question is similar to: Boot drops to a (initramfs) prompts/busybox. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You have a 'missing disk' hence why it dropped to the initramfs prompt.  The ACPI errors are not related to that necessarily.

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached End of Standard Support last year, and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (cost maybe involved) if you wish but community support (such as this site) no longer exists, though SE Unix & Linux allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic or Canonical who provide ESM/Pro services.
